# OpenERP onchange event to get details from Parent table

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Sorry, this is a beginner question.

I have the following tables in OpenERP:

Payment Table (Parent Table)

```
---------------------------------
| ID | OR_DATE     | TRANS_TYPE |
---------------------------------
| 1  | 2010-10-15  | 1          |
---------------------------------
| 2  | 2010-10-30  | 2          |
---------------------------------
| 3  | 2010-10-15  | 1          |
---------------------------------
```

Payment Detail Table (Child Table)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | OTH_PYMT_ID  | DESCRIPTION      | ACCOUNT_TITLE_ID  | AMOUNT |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1            | Cash Payment  1  | 1                 |  1,000 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 1            | Check Payment 1  | 2                 |  1,000 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 2            | Cash Payment  2  | 1                 |  1,000 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Payment Types Table (Reference Table)

```
-----------------------------------------
| ID  | DESCRIPTION      | ACCOUNT_CODE | 
-----------------------------------------
| 1   | Cash             | ACCCODE001   |
-----------------------------------------
| 2   | Check            | ACCCODE002   |
-----------------------------------------
| 3   | Credit Card      | ACCCODE003   |
-----------------------------------------
```

I have 2 classes in OpenERP with the following structure:

Python Code:

```
payment(osv.osv):
    """
    OpenERP Model : payment
    """

    _name = 'payment'
    _description = __doc__

    _columns = {
        'or_date': fields.date('OR Date'),
        'trans_type':fields.many2one('payment.type', "Transaction Type"),
        'oth_pymt_det_ids':fields.one2many('payment.detail', 'oth_pymt_id', 'Details'),
    }
class payment()

class payment_detail(osv.osv):
    """
    OpenERP Model : payment_detail
    """

    _name = 'payment.detail'
    _description = __doc__

    #onchange_description function goes here

    _columns = {
        'oth_pymt_id':fields.many2one('payment', 'Payment'),
        'description':fields.char('Description', size=100 ),
        'account_title_id':fields.char('Account Title', size=20),
        'amount': fields.float('Amount', digits=(16, 2)),
    }

payment_detail()
```

XML Code:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="payment_form">
    <field name="name">Payments</field>
    <field name="model">payment</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Payments">
            <group col="4" colspan="4">
                <field name="trans_type" />
                <field name="or_date" />                                              
                <field name="oth_pymt_det_ids" mode="tree" nolabel="1" colspan="4">
                    <tree string="Payment Details" editable="top">
                        <field name="description" on_change="onchange_description()"/>
                        <field name="account_title_id"/>
                        <field name="amount"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </group> 
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

How do I add an `onchange_description` event inside the `payment_detail` class which automatically fetches and prints details from "payment" table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the `{}` button in the editor to mark a whole block of text as code. That way it gets formatted nicely.

Comment: What do you mean 'automatically fetches and prints detail from "payment" table'? Do you mean that you want the 'description' field to be automatically update to something when the parent (payment) entry changing?

Comment: Hi @jayven I mean I should be able to print the details from payment table (ID, OR_DATE, TRANS_TYPE)

Comment: Well, onchange event is called only when you are changing the description filed [see the doc](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/events/events.html). I think that is not what you want. Maybe you can define the description field as a function field [see here](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#functional-fields)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **parent** parameter. You can find an example in [sale module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/7066/sale/sale_view.xml#L135) ([python file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/7066/sale/sale.py#L1189))

In your case, try with something like

```
<field name="description" on_change="onchange_description(description, parent.or_date)"/>
```